# Error with String converting to array swift Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to teaching myself Xcode.  I'm getting an error in the print func. Thanks for the help.

```
struct ScoreList {
    private(set) var scores: [Int]

    init(scores: [Int]) {
        self.scores = scores.sorted()
    }

    mutating func addScore(score: Int) {
        scores.append(score)
        scores.sort()
    }
}

func print() {
    ScoreList(scores: [
        gregNetScore.text, dannyNetScore.text, tunaNetScore.text,
    ])
}
```

Comment: Your init expects an array of integers not an array of optional strings

Comment: change `gregNetScore.text` to `Int(gregNetScore.text!) ?? .zero` and so on

Comment: You may not want to name a function `print` as that is already an important system function.

Comment: There is an extra comma after ```tunaNetScore.text``` in the ```print``` function.

Comment: @NDCoder that’s ok. It doesn’t make any difference AFAIR

Comment: Your sent the array of strings to the `init` function which needs an array of integers.